# How to assign value to the unique_ptr after declaring it?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // unique_ptr

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<char*> char_ptr;

    char_ptr = (char*)"anisha";
    return 0;
}
```

I want to assign some value to that unique_ptr elsewhere in the code.
This gives the following error: `char_ptr = (char*)"anisha";`

```
error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::unique_ptr<char*>’ and ‘char*’)
     char_ptr = (char*)"anisha";
```

How to assign value to the `unique_ptr` after declaring it?

Comment: Use [make_unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique)

Comment: That assignment is illustrative, right? You aren't really gonna have it hold the address of a string literal?

Comment: please show an example @StoryTeller I have forgotten.

Comment: If you want to store a `char*` in your smart pointer you are declaring it wrong. It should be `std::unique_ptr<char> char_ptr;`

Comment: If you're going to put weird pointer creation in your question, you need to adjust your question to be specific about that strange pointer allocation, otherwise the answers you get are going to either not answer your question or confuse people who see this and don't understand that the weird pointer assignment is irrelevant.  Voting to close based on this oddity.   Why not just use a normal pointer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use std::make_unique.
Here is edit to your code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory> // unique_ptr

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<char*> char_ptr;

    //char_ptr = (char*)"anisha";
    char_ptr = std::make_unique<char*>((char*)"anisha");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi what if it is c++ version is older that 14?

Comment: @susil95, then use method described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78038028/1418463) answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't naively store a pointer to a string literal in a `unique_ptr`. The pointer here assumes it *owns* the referenced object and can free it. But it can't be owned by the pointer, since string literals have static storage duration.

If you want to store a modifiable c-string in a `unique_ptr` you need to alloacte and copy, you can't hit the type system over the head with a cast and carry on with your merry life.

So a utility that turns string literals to unique pointers can look like this:

```
template<std::size_t N>
auto literal_dup(char const (&lit)[N]) {
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<char[]>(N);
    std::copy(lit, lit + N, &ptr[0]);
    return ptr; 
}
```

Using it will look like this:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> c_string;
c_string = literal_dup("anisha");
```

We need to use the array form of `unique_ptr` to make sure it deallocates the buffer correctly and with no undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In order to assign a new value to a `std::unique_ptr` use the [`reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) method.

However, a big word of caution regarding the use of this method is that the `std::unique_ptr` object will try to dispose of the managed pointer by invoking a `Deleter` function on the managed pointer when the `std::unique_ptr` object will be being destroyed or when the managed pointer will be being replaced by another value.

The default `Deleter` calls the [`delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) operator with the managed pointer.

That being said, if the `std::unique_ptr` is used with its default `Deleter`, the pointer assigned to the `std::unique_ptr` using the `reset()` method must point to a memory previously obtained from a call to the [`new`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) operator. Otherwise, undefined behavior will result.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int> u_ptr;
    
    int * p = new int(100);

    u_ptr.reset(p);
    
    std::cout << *u_ptr << '\n'; // outputs 100

    // u_ptr goes out of scope and calls delete(p); Memory is properly deallocated.
}
```

But, it's possible to use a `Deleter` function that does nothing and in this case it will be safe to assign the value of any pointer to the `std::unique_ptr`. However, in this case care needs to be taken to ensure that the pointer stored in the `std::unique_ptr` does not outlive the object where it points to. Such usage of the unique pointer could be counterintuitive:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct fake_deleter
{
    void operator()(int *){}
};


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<int, fake_deleter> u_ptr;
    
    int n = 100;

    u_ptr.reset(&n);
    
    std::cout << *u_ptr << '\n'; // outputs 100

    /* u_ptr goes out of scope and calls fake_deleter(&n);
       which does nothing. This is correct in this example */
}
```